# iPython with Django : CommandError: No notebook (Python) kernel specs found

Tags: django, python-2.7, ipython

I'm new to `jupyter/ipython` and `django`.
I have `Django 1.9.5` installed on `Ubuntu 16.04` and my application is running fine. I want to configure `iPython(version 5.1.0)` to be used with my `Django` application. Basically trying to call the iPython notebook (browser) from django which later can be used extensively in the application through a user interface.

When I try to run the command below

```
$./manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I get an error:

```
[W 13:46:39.247 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
[I 13:46:41.082 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found
[I 13:46:41.114 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 13:46:41.399 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 13:46:41.399 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 13:46:41.409 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 13:46:41.507 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
**CommandError: No notebook (Python) kernel specs found**
```

To resolve this I tried:
ipython2 kernelspec install-self --user

Under home directory `.local/share/jupyter/kernels` folder there is a `kernel.json` file

I'm not sure why I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestion will be very helpful in resolving this issue. Thank you.

To achieve launching iPython notebook from Django I tried the following:

1. Installed the django-extensions: `pip install django-extensions`
2. In django `settings.py` file added the line `django_extensions` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. Ran `ipython profile create` and uncommented this line : 
   `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['django_notebook']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the Jupyter Notebook extensions which resolved the issue:

```
$conda remove nb_conda

$ python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
[I 09:09:19.586 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to    /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 09:09:19.831 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/venkateshpatil1/dir/dir1/SC
[I 09:09:19.832 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 09:09:19.832 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 09:09:19.833 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```